# Dynamically set the value of the input based on the input been changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following :-

```
 $("#b1,#b2,#b3,#b4,#b5").change(function () {
        $("#c1").val(Math.round(($(this).val() * $("#Doctor_MedicarePatients").val())/100));
```

can i make my code dynamic so if b1 is changed then to set the value of c1 (as shown above), while if b2 is changed to change the value of c2, and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
$("#b1,#b2,#b3,#b4,#b5").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace('b', '');
  $("#c" + id).val(Math.round(($(this).val() * $("#Doctor_MedicarePatients").val()) / 100));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can link your in/out pairs through `data-` attributes:

```
$("[data-in]").change(function() {
  var link = $(this).data("in");
  $("[data-out=" + link + "]").val(Math.round(($(this).val() * $("#Doctor_MedicarePatients").val()) / 100));
});
```

and replace all your #b1,#b2 / #c1,#c2 with data-in/data-out, eg:

```
<!-- was b1 / c1 -->
<input data-in="1" type="text">
<input data-out="1" type="text">

<!-- was b2 / c2 -->
<input data-in="2" type="text">
<input data-out="2" type="text">
```

this has the additional benefit that if you add new pairs `#b6,#b7` (becoming `data-in="7"` etc) then you don't need to make any code changes and it will just auto-magically-work

Answer (score -2):

On your snippet what you have is if #b1, #b2, #b3, #b4 ***or*** #b5 change, then #c1 will get the value of the b that changed. You need to put them separately. Like this

```
$("#b1).change(function () {
  $("#c1").val(Math.round(($(this).val() * $("#Doctor_MedicarePatients").val())/100)
}); 

$("#b2).change(function () {
  $("#c2").val(Math.round(($(this).val() * $("#Doctor_MedicarePatients").val())/100)
}); 

$("#b3).change(function () {
  $("#c3").val(Math.round(($(this).val() * $("#Doctor_MedicarePatients").val())/100)
}); 

$("#b4).change(function () {
  $("#c4").val(Math.round(($(this).val() * $("#Doctor_MedicarePatients").val())/100)
}); 

$("#b5).change(function () {
  $("#c5").val(Math.round(($(this).val() * $("#Doctor_MedicarePatients").val())/100)
});
```

Comment: first of you are missing a `"` in `$("#b5)`, Secondly the way you surgest is not optimal, the op aims to make it dynamic, and your way is very static